# Whisper Module Python Speech to Text

Tags: python, machine-learning, openai-api, openai-whisper

I'm just trying to create a simple speech to text transcriber using the openai whisper module and streamlit for web application but having some problems.

It is giving me error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Satyam Singh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 565, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\Satyam Singh\Desktop\Python Project\app.py", line 19, in <module>
    transcription = model.transcribe(audio_file)
  File "C:\Users\Satyam Singh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\whisper\transcribe.py", line 84, in transcribe     
    mel = log_mel_spectrogram(audio)
  File "C:\Users\Satyam Singh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\whisper\audio.py", line 112, in log_mel_spectrogram    audio = torch.from_numpy(audio)
**TypeError: expected np.ndarray (got NoneType)**
```

Here's my code

```
import streamlit as st
import whisper
from audio_recorder_streamlit import audio_recorder


# App Title Name
st.title("Speech to Text")

# uploading an audio file
# audio_file = st.file_uploader("Upload Audio", type=["wav","mp3","m4a"])
audio_file = audio_recorder()
if audio_file:
    st.audio(audio_file, format="audio/wav")


model = whisper.load_model("base")
st.text("Whisper Model Loaded")

transcription = model.transcribe(audio_file)
print(transcription['text'])

                        
if st.sidebar.button("Transcribe Audio"):
    if audio_file is not None:
        st.sidebar.success("Transcribing Audio")
        transcription = model.transcribe(audio_file.name)
        st.sidebar.success("Transcription Complete")
        st.text(transcription["text"])
    else:
        st.sidebar.error("Please Upload an Audio File")
```

I want something like [Baseten](https://app.baseten.co/apps/2BYeZGB/operator_views/MPXGlJ0)

I want this code to work or something more innovative which works same way like this one or Baseten.

Comment: Hi Satyam, could you please provide the output of `audio_file` - as this is what is being passed to the `model.transcribe()` function, and this is where the code is failing.

Comment: You can simply use any kind of wav, MP3 audio file

Comment: Right, but what is the contents of the `audio_file` variable in your code? What output does it print?